# How to get multiple records for same model with Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a basic recipes app but am having trouble allowing the user to input multiple ingredients for one recipe. The array of permitted params for the ingredients ends up empty. So I guess my question is - how do I permit the array of ingredients?

My controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new
end

def create
    safe_params = params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :instruction, :category_id)
    ingredient_params = params.require(:recipe).permit(:ingredient => [])
    @recipe = Recipe.new(safe_params)
    @recipe.save
    ingredient_params.each do |i|
        @recipe.ingredients << Ingredient.find_or_create_by(name: i[:ingredient][:name])
    end
    render body: YAML::dump(ingredient_params)
    #redirect_to index_path(id: @recipe.id)
end

end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe, :url => create_path) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :category %>
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|c|[c.title, c.id]}) %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title%>

<%= f.label :instruction %>
<%= f.text_area(:instruction, size: "50x10") %>

<%= f.fields_for "ingredients[]", @ingredient do |i| %>
    <%= i.label :name %>
    <%= i.text_field :name %>
    <%= i.text_field :name %>
    <%= i.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

Comment: what permit error can you see in log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here, I'll just provide what I'd do:

```
#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @recipe = Recipe.new
        @recipe.ingredients.new
    end

    def create
        @recipe = Recipe.new safe_params
        @recipe.save
    end

    private

    def safe_params
       params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :instruction, :category_id, ingredients_attributes: [:name])
    end

end

#app/views/recipes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>

    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>

    <%= f.label :instruction %>
    <%= f.text_area(:instruction, size: "50x10") %>

    <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
       <%= i.label :name %>
       <%= i.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

If you wanted to have multiple `ingredients` fields, you'll have to *build* multiple objects in the controller:

```
def new
   @recipe = Recipe.new
   3.times do
      @recipe.ingedients.build
   end
end
```

Everything else looks like it will work well.

--

As an extra, if you want to populate `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships, you'll be able to just pass the `[relationship]_ids` parameter:

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :ingredient_ids, Ingredient.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will only work for currently existing ingredients. If you want to create new ingredients, the above will work.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks! My only challenge now is that I need the form to handle both existing and new ingredients. If you have any thoughts on that I would love to hear. If not, I'm sure I can figure it out eventually. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll be best looking up about [`has_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). I can write an update if you wish; it will be out of context of the question though

Comment: No need to write an update. I'll try to figure it out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need to make few changes to your code

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    # here you can decide how many ingredients do you want. (Not in form looping through text fields)
    3.times do
      ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.build
   end    
end
```

so fields for ingredients were get generated for three times.

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
    <%= i.label :name %>
    <%= i.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Please go through following link, it will clear your idea about nested forms

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1